# proc_open() use the same PID when ran multiple times in the same script

Tags: php, process

I'm currently trying to wrote a worker launcher script. I use `proc_open` to trigger process execution. It works nicely with one worker but when I try to make multiple `proc_open` only the first one actually run the process and the others gave me the same PID using the `proc_get_status` function...

Some code :

```
<?php
$procs = [];
$count = 10;
$script = "date";
while(--$count > 0)
{
    $proc = new Processus(
        $script,
        null,
        [1 => STDOUT]
    );
    $proc->open();
    $procs[] = $proc;
}

while(true) {
    foreach($procs as $key => $proc) {
        $status = $proc->getStatus();
        if(false === $status['running']) {
            finishProcess($proc, $status);
            unset($procs[$key]);
        }
    }

    if(0 === count($procs)) {
        break;
    }
}
```

In my `finishProcess` function I got for each process the `$status['running'] === false` but I got the same PID.

Actually the ouput is filled with the `date` command result only once... I tried to played with different pipe descriptors but can't make it works...

Is it possible in PHP to run multiple sub-process in the same script ?

My `Process` object is just a wrapper around `proc_*` functions.

Thanks for your help :)